# May I use True for Python type hintings?

Tags: python, python-typing

Can I or should I use True or False for Python type hinting?

```
def can_be_used_as_divider(num) -> True:
    if num == 0:
        raise ValueError('The number must not be zero!')

    return True
```

I have a function that raises some error in different cases and returns True if it doesn't.
Should I raise errors, return errors or there is any good pattern for this?

Comment: Don't return anything.

Comment: raising and catching an error is usually a lot slower than just returning `False` and checking if the return is false ... so once you application starts becoming slow you should remove that raise and return false instead ... you also have a finite number of nested try/catch so watch out that you don't hit it.

Comment: @luk2302 Judging by the name of the function, I'd say not returning anything would be the opposite of what you'd expect (because `None` evaluates to false)

Comment: You named the function as if it should return `False` instead of raising an error.

Comment: The way this usually is used is to name the function `assert_not_zero` and have it raise an error if the number is 0, and do nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `typing.Literal`.
Example:

```py
from typing import Literal

def can_be_used_as_divider(num) -> Literal[True]:
    if num == 0:
        raise ValueError('The number must not be zero!')

    return True
```

Comment: Why can't I use just ` -> True` , PyCharm doesn't mark it as an error? What's the point of returning something if the value is always the same?

Comment: @Stupidgenius because `True` is not a type. It is an instance of the type `bool`. And type annotations are done with... well... _types_. The `Literal` construct is sort of a workaround by broadening the concept of a _type_ to encompass specific subsets of instances of "real" types. In that sense `Literal["a", "b"]` is a _strict subtype_ of `str` and `Literal[True]` is a strict subtype of `bool`.